# NDSolve unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I'm trying to solve a set of differential-algebraic equations with boundary conditions:

$A\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}=[c_{F}-2c_{D}(x)+c_{C}(x)]F$

$c_{D}(x)=0.1\exp(-0.2253 - 76.5596\psi(x) - 1.1149)$

$c_{C}(x)=0.2\exp(-1.3305 + 38.2798\psi(x) - 0.3459)$

$\psi\,'(0)=0,\psi(\frac{1}{2})=0$

With the following code, shooting method is used to find the Dirichlet BC at $x=0$ to use `NDsolve` to solve the DAE

```
Clear["Global`*"]

A = 5.31251*10^-10;
F = 96485.33252;
cF = 1000;

(*Obtain Dirichlet condition of psi at x=0 by shooting method*)
fun[y_?NumericQ] := Module[{eqns, sol, ics, x, psi, cD, cC},
   eqns = {A*D[psi[x], x, x] == (cF - 2*cD[x] + cC[x])*F,
     cD[x] == 0.1*Exp[-0.2253 - 76.5596*psi[x] - 1.1149],
     cC[x] == 0.2*Exp[-1.3305 + 38.2798*psi[x] - 0.3459]};
   ics = {psi[0] == y, psi'[x] == 0 /. x -> 0};
   sol = 
    NDSolve[{eqns, ics}, {psi[x], cD[x], cC[x]}, {x, 0, 1/2}][[1]];
   psi[x] /. sol /. x -> 1/2];
ic = FindRoot[fun[x], {x, 0}]

dae = {A*D[psi[x], x, x] == (cF - 2*cD[x] + cC[x])*F,
   cD[x] == 0.1*Exp[-0.2253 - 76.5596*psi[x] - 1.1149],
   cC[x] == 0.2*Exp[-1.3305 + 38.2798*psi[x] - 0.3459]};
bcs = {psi[0] == x /. ic[[1]], D[psi[x], x] == 0 /. x -> 0};

(*Solve the differential equation using NDSolve*)
sol = NDSolve[{dae, bcs}, {psi, cD, cC}, {x, 0, 1/2}];
```

The `NDSolve` returns the following error:

`Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.`

Even if the system of DAE is converted to an ODE to eliminate the need for shooting method, applying NDSolve gives the error:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

A = 5.31251*10^-10;
F = 96485.33252;
cF = 1000;

ode = {A*
     D[psi[x], x, 
      x] == (cF - 2*0.1*Exp[-0.2253 - 76.5596*psi[x] - 1.1149] + 
       0.2*Exp[-1.3305 + 38.2798*psi[x] - 0.3459])*F};
bcs = {psi[1/2] == 0, D[psi[x], x] == 0 /. x -> 0};

(*Solve the differential equation using NDSolve*)
sol = NDSolve[{ode, bcs}, {psi}, {x, 0, 1/2}];
```

`` NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 2.012990504102674`*^-9, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. ``

Are there any methods that I can use to get around this? I'm new to numerical method, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: You could try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions. It requires an understanding of the problem, which I don't have at present. Knowing what gave rise to the system your solving might help.

Comment: It also would be nice to isolate the problem for site users.  (Which `NDSolve` gives the error, the first or second? How is `Plot` related to the problem? And so forth.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 The first NDSolve failed, and even if I made the DAEs into an ODE (to eliminate the need for shooting method), NDSolve also failed to solve using the two BCs stated above, giving the error `NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 2.012990504102674*^-9, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.`  `Plot` is just for plotting the solution, in this case it isn't related to the problem of NDSolve. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: @MichaelE2 This system arose from the calculation of concentration of ions in a membrane. Currently I only have the 2 BCs stated to work with, are there any methods I can implement for NDSolve for this?

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating the unnecessary variables converts the first system from a DAE to an ODE, which gets rid of the problem complained of in the OP:

```
fun[y_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{eqns, sol, ics, x, psi, cD, cC}, 
   eqns = {A*
       D[psi[x], x, 
        x] == (cF - 
         2*(0.1*Exp[-0.2253 - 76.5596*psi[x] - 1.1149]) + (0.2*
           Exp[-1.3305 + 38.2798*psi[x] - 0.3459]))*F};
   ics = {psi[0] == y, psi'[x] == 0 /. x -> 0};
   NDSolveValue[{eqns, ics}, {psi[x]}, {x, 0, 1/2}]
   ];
```

However, the second derivative of `psi` grows so fast, other problems arise, naturally, such as singularities.

The second derivative as a function of `psi`:

```
Plot[(cF - 
    2*(0.1*Exp[-0.2253 - 76.5596*psi[x] - 1.1149]) + (0.2*
      Exp[-1.3305 + 38.2798*psi[x] - 0.3459]))*F/A, {psi[x], 0, 1}]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: With the function `fun` presented, it will be called by `FindRoot` in the subsequent line, and from there `NDSolveVelue` will fail, giving the error `NDSolveValue::ndsz: At x$7057 == 2.012990266193402*^-9, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.` As mentioned by you, singularities may occur, hence do you mind suggesting any inbuilt numerical methods that can solve this problem?

Comment: @JackL The two plots show a large second derivative in the neighborhood of `psi == 0` (right), which is a BC in your setup. The left plot shows rapid growth of the second derivative, suggesting that a singularity might be inevitable. It's a feature of the equations that any accurate numerical method would show. If there is a way to rescale `psi`, it might turn out that the singularity is a numerical artifact of poor scaling. Perhaps recheck the equations.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for the suggestion, I'll look into it.